# Drag and drop an image from a container to another - Flex

Tags: apache-flex, drag-and-drop, bitmap

I need a way to drag and drop an image from a container to another. I have tried a few different ways but I guess the drag & drop thing is still eluding me. Anyway, here's what I am trying to do, A container will contains a few bitmap/vector image (what's the best way for this? Tile Group? Or?) and then I want to be able to drag any of the image onto another larger Image inside of a Panel. Just like dragging shapes in Photoshop.

No code here, as I am completely lost on how to go about it. I found a few tip/tutorial here and there but none which I could understand easily or adapt to my need. So, any help?

Edit 1 : Got so far till now :

```
        public function beginDrag( mouseEvent:MouseEvent ):void
        {
          var dragInitiator:IUIComponent = mouseEvent.currentTarget as IUIComponent;

            var dragSource:DragSource = new DragSource();
            dragSource.addData(mouseEvent.currentTarget.source, "items");

            var dragProxy:Image = new Image();
            dragProxy.source = mouseEvent.currentTarget.source;
            dragProxy.setActualSize(mouseEvent.currentTarget.width,mouseEvent.currentTarget.height)
            DragManager.doDrag(dragInitiator, dragSource, mouseEvent, dragProxy);
        }
        public function acceptDrop( dragEvent:DragEvent ):void
        {
            var dropTarget:IUIComponent = dragEvent.currentTarget as IUIComponent;
            var dragSource:DragSource = dragEvent.dragSource;
            if (dragSource.hasFormat("items"))
            {
                DragManager.acceptDragDrop(Image(dragEvent.currentTarget));
            }
        }
        public function handleDrop( dragEvent:DragEvent ):void
        {
            var dragInitiator:IUIComponent = dragEvent.dragInitiator;
            var dropTarget:IUIComponent = dragEvent.currentTarget as IUIComponent;

            var items:String = dragEvent.dragSource.dataForFormat("items") as String;
            var img:Image = new Image();
            img.x=dragEvent.localX;
            img.y=dragEvent.localY;
            img.width = 50;
            img.height=50;
            img.source=items.toString();
            var bitmap:Bitmap= Bitmap(img.content);
            myImage.addChild(img);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "container" but overall you want to use MOUSE_DOWN/MOUSE_UP event listeners on the shapes, with startDrag() and stopDrag() calls in the listener functions.

Comment: Well, not sure if container is the right term. But here's what I want. I want to keep a few images in a say, Tile Group and from that I want to drag and drop any Image on to another larger image that is inside a Panel. Do you have any link in mind I can go through for the events you mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to enable drag-and-drop is to use a List component (you can give it a custom layout, such as TileLayout). See [Using drag-and-drop with list-based controls](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7cfd.html) from the Flex documentation for some example code that should get you started.

If, for some reason, a List won't work for you, you're going to need to play around with DragManager directly. The article [Manually adding drag-and-drop support](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7cfe.html) describes all the required events and provides example code.

Comment: Got started with a bit of code I found here & there. Anyway, the code is updated in my question, and the problem now I am facing is that everytime the image is dragged and dropped actually a copy of it is created and drop on target. Now, once it's inside the target (that is, Image control with the larger image) I need it to be still draggable/droppable at a different co-ordinate on the Image control, but without copying the Image. That is the image should completely move to new position. How do I do that?

Comment: If you listen for the dragComplete event on your drag initiator, you can handle cleanup after a drop. You might also want to look at DragManager.showFeedback(DragManager.MOVE) to specify that a drag is a move instead of a copy.